# calling render() function inside a class in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have written a simple ReactJS code in which I am trying to call render() function from inside of the Store class but I am getting error. If I am calling ReactDOM.render() function from outside of the Store class then the this.state.data is not accessible outside of the Store class. So please tell what should I do?

**Code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.jsx';

class Store extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
         data: 
         [
            {
               name: 'First...',
               id: 1
            },

            {
               name: 'Second...',
               id: 2
            },

            {
               name: 'Third...',
               id: 3
            }
         ]
      }
   };

    render(
        <App storeData={this.state.data} />,
        document.getElementById('app')
    );
}
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR in ./main.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/username/Desktop/fluxExample/main.js
: Unexpected token (31:2)

  29 |
  30 |  render(
> 31 |          <App storeData={this.state.data} />,
     |          ^
  32 |          document.getElementById('app')
  33 |  );
  34 | }

 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-serve
r ./main.js
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: Your syntax is not valid at all. Also you seem to be confusing mounting your application and a React component. Your Store probably doesn't need to be a React Component.

Answer (score 1):

You need to render `Store` component and then `App` as a child of `Store`. The render function inside the Store needs to return a Valid React component like

```
class Store extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
         data: 
         [
            {
               name: 'First...',
               id: 1
            },

            {
               name: 'Second...',
               id: 2
            },

            {
               name: 'Third...',
               id: 3
            }
         ]
      }
   };

   render() {
       return (
            <App storeData={this.state.data} />
       )
   }

}

ReactDOM.render(
        <Store/>,
        document.getElementById('app')
    );
```